# How can the client and server pause to wait for the other to send the next message?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am building a java client and server that plays a guess my number game. The server tells the client the range of numbers, the client enters a guess, and the server returns "Try Again" or the number if the client guessed the correct number. The server also needs to be multithreaded.

I have up to the part where the server sends the range but I cannot get the server and the client to pause at the points indicated by the comments in Client.java and in WorkerRunnable.java. I need the server and client to pause at this point so that it will wait to receive the message from the corresponding sender.

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.IOException;

public class GameServer implements Runnable{

    public int serverPort = 8080;
    public ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
    public boolean isStopped = false;
    public Thread runningThread = null;

public GameServer() {
    this.serverPort = 8080;
}

public GameServer(int port) {
    this.serverPort = port;
}

public void run() {

    synchronized(this) {
        this.runningThread = Thread.currentThread();
    }
    openServerSocket();
    while(!this.isStopped) {
        Socket clientSocket = null;
        try {
            clientSocket = this.serverSocket.accept();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            if(this.isStopped) {
                System.out.println("The server has been stopped.");
                return;
            }
        }
        new Thread(new WorkerRunnable(clientSocket, "Oi m8")).start();
    }
    System.out.println("The server has been stopped.");

}

    public synchronized void stop() {
        this.isStopped = true;
        try {
            this.serverSocket.close();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error closing server.");    
        }
    }

    private void openServerSocket() {
        try {
            this.serverSocket = new ServerSocket(this.serverPort);
        }catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error opening server.");
        }
    }

}


public class Server {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        GameServer server = new GameServer(9000);
        new Thread(server).start();

        System.out.println("The Server has started.");

    }

}


import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {

   public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{

       Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 9000);

        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

        String serverMessage;
        String clientMessage;

        serverMessage = inFromServer.readLine();
        System.out.println(serverMessage);

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        String num = inFromUser.readLine();

        //I need for the client to wait here as well.

        System.out.println("ugh");

    }

} 


import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WorkerRunnable implements Runnable{

    public Socket clientSocket = null;
    public String serverText = null;

    public int number = -1; 
    public int guessCount = 0;

    public WorkerRunnable(Socket clientSocket, String serverText) {

        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.serverText = serverText;
        this.guessCount = 0;

    }

    public void run() {

        try {

            BufferedReader inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            OutputStream output = clientSocket.getOutputStream();

            Random rand = new Random();
            number = rand.nextInt(10);

            output.write(("Guess an integer between 0 and 10." + number).getBytes());

            //I need for the server to wait here

            output.close();


        }catch (IOException e) {

            System.out.println("Something went wrong.");

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Why? They will block in every read until data arrives. Why do you need them to block afterwards?

Comment: Yes that was the problem I was running into. How can I fix it?

Comment: It's not a problem and it doesn't need fixing. In fact it's the answer to the question in your title, which doesn't agree with the body of your question. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: What I need to be able to do is after the server sends the message about the range the client will enter a number to guess, send that number back to the server, the server will check the number, and send a message back. This process can be repeated a number of times. When I tried to implement this the server wouldn't send the message about the range. I tried to get the client and the server to enter into a while loop to wait for a new message from the sender however this yielded the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are reading lines but you aren't writing lines. You need to add a line terminator to the messages.

It has nothing to do with your title or what you're asking for in the body of your question, which don't agree with each other anyway. The reads will block until data arrives. In this case `readLine()` will block until a line terminator or end of stream arrives.

Comment: Thank you. This fixed my problem.